# If Current URL is Home Do Something

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, if-statement, pathname

So I have a JS script (running with Jquery), and I want to do various things depending on the current page.

So I have this:

```
var current_url = location.pathname;
```

On the home page of the website (i.e. mysite.com), current_url logs as '/'.

But for some reason I just can't get this if statement to evaluate…

```
if (current_url == '/') {
    $('header').append(autoflowside_content);
    console.log('Home!');
}
```

Am I missing something??

Thank you!

Comment: When is this if block reached? Do you have it in your dom ready function?

Comment: Aha! It was in the DOM ready function, BUT there was a bit of a vicious circle going on. Because the relevant bit of code wasn't being inserted (autoflowside_content) by the if function it broke a line of JS right under the DOM ready function and so the if statement wasn't reached. Thank you for making me check that!

Answer (score 1):

var current_url = location.pathname,

location.path names returns you the path after your host name i.e. after mysite.com in your case. But there no segment after your host name, so you will not be able to find nothing.

Please find some of the properties available in window.location given below and choose respective property required for your requirement.
window.location contains

```
         origin: "http://stackoverflow.com", 
         hash: "",
         host: "stackoverflow.com",
         hostname: "stackoverflow.com",
         href: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023213/if-current-url-is-something",
         origin: "http://stackoverflow.com"
         pathname: "/questions/26023213/if-current-url-is-home-do-something",
         port: "",
         protocol: "http:",
```

}